# Karma setup don't see the .ts files

Tags: karma-jasmine, angular2-testing

I have a big old project on Angular2, which I didn't start, and now I need to add tests there. I setup jasmine and karma, but, unfortunately, when I start "npm test", it don't see the .ts files, so I see the result only in .js-tests.

Here are the setup code:
system.config.js

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'src',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

karma.conf.js

```
// #docregion
module.exports = function(config) {

  var appBase    = 'src/';       // transpiled app JS and map files
  var appSrcBase = 'src/';       // app source TS files
  var appAssets  = '/base/src/'; // component assets fetched by Angular's compiler

  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'), // click "Debug" in browser to see it
      require('karma-htmlfile-reporter') // crashing w/ strange socket error
    ],

    customLaunchers: {
      // From the CLI. Not used here but interesting
      // chrome setup for travis CI using chromium
      Chrome_travis_ci: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    },
    files: [
      // System.js for module loading
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',

      // Polyfills
      'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js',
      'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',

      // zone.js
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',

      // RxJs
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

      // Paths loaded via module imports:
      // Angular itself
      {pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false},

      {pattern: 'systemjs.config.js', included: false, watched: false},
      'karma-test-shim.js',

      // transpiled application & spec code paths loaded via module imports
      {pattern: appBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true},
      {pattern: appBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: true},

      // Asset (HTML & CSS) paths loaded via Angular's component compiler
      // (these paths need to be rewritten, see proxies section)
      {pattern: appBase + '**/*.html', included: false, watched: true},
      {pattern: appBase + '**/*.css', included: false, watched: true},

      // Paths for debugging with source maps in dev tools
      {pattern: appSrcBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false},
      // {pattern: appBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false}
    ],

    // Proxied base paths for loading assets
    proxies: {
      // required for component assets fetched by Angular's compiler
      "/src/": appAssets
    },

    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {},
    // disabled HtmlReporter; suddenly crashing w/ strange socket error
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],//'html'],

    // HtmlReporter configuration
    htmlReporter: {
      // Open this file to see results in browser
      outputFile: '_test-output/tests.html',

      // Optional
      pageTitle: 'Unit Tests',
      subPageTitle: __dirname
    },

    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  })
}
```

karma-test-shim.js

```
// #docregion
// /*global jasmine, __karma__, window*/
Error.stackTraceLimit = 0; // "No stacktrace"" is usually best for app testing.

// Uncomment to get full stacktrace output. Sometimes helpful, usually not.
// Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity; //

jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1000;

var builtPath = '/base/src/';

__karma__.loaded = function () { };

function isJsFile(path) {
  return path.slice(-3) == '.js';
}

function isSpecFile(path) {
  return /\.spec\.(.*\.)?js$/.test(path);
}

function isBuiltFile(path) {
  return isJsFile(path) && (path.substr(0, builtPath.length) == builtPath);
}

var allSpecFiles = Object.keys(window.__karma__.files)
  .filter(isSpecFile)
  .filter(isBuiltFile);

System.config({
  baseURL: '/base',
  // Extend usual application package list with test folder
  packages: { 'testing': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' } },

  // Assume npm: is set in `paths` in systemjs.config
  // Map the angular testing umd bundles
  map: {
    '@angular/core/testing': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/common/testing': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler/testing': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/http/testing': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/router/testing': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/forms/testing': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms-testing.umd.js',
  },
});

System.import('systemjs.config.js')
  .then(initTestBed)
  .then(initTesting);

function initTestBed(){
  return Promise.all([
    System.import('@angular/core/testing'),
    System.import('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing')
  ])

  .then(function (providers) {
    var coreTesting    = providers[0];
    var browserTesting = providers[1];

    coreTesting.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
      browserTesting.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
      browserTesting.platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
  })
}

// Import all spec files and start karma
function initTesting () {
  return Promise.all(
    allSpecFiles.map(function (moduleName) {
      return System.import(moduleName);
    })
  )
  .then(__karma__.start, __karma__.error);
}
```

I know, that it is simplier to use solutions of angular-seed or angular-CLI, but it's really hard to migrate this huge project to new platform, so please help! )
What should I do to my "npm test" finally see the .spec.ts files?

Answer (score 0):

This function is capturing only `.js` files:

```
function isSpecFile(path) {
  return /\.spec\.(.*\.)?js$/.test(path);
}
```

To fix that, change to an expression that will include `.ts` files, such as:

```
function isSpecFile(path) {
  return /\.spec\.(.*\.)?[jt]s$/.test(path);
}
```

Similar issue with:

```
function isJsFile(path) {
  return path.slice(-3) == '.js';
}
```

...which could be changed to:

```
function isJsFile(path) {
  return path.slice(-3) == '.js' || path.slice(-3) == '.ts';
}
```

I'd probably change the name `isJsFile` to `isJsOrTsFile` too, but you'd have to replace all instances.